# Problema al actualizar un VarChar de SQLite en Java

Tags: java, sqlite

mi problema es el siguiente, tengo un programa de stock básico. El stock maneja artículos, estos mismos tienen id(int), nombre(string), precio(float), categoría(string) el dilema esta a la hora de actualizar porque me actualiza el precio, la categoría pero no el nombre! me esta sacando de quicio ni siquiera me tira un error desde donde comenzar a investigar, si alguien pueda ayudar, gracias.

---

aqui esta el codigo de mi articuloDAO:

```
//solamente el metodo de actualizar articulo subi, si necestin mas revisen el github
public void actualizarArticulo(Articulo art) {
        Conexion con = new Conexion();
        try {
            con.conectar();
            //Esta consulta es para obtener y guardar el numero de id de la categoria del art
            int idCat=0;
            PreparedStatement st = con.getConnection().prepareStatement("select * from categorias where nombreCat=(?);");
            st.setString(1, art.getCategoria());
            ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery();
            idCat=rs.getInt("idCat");

            //Esta consulta es para actualizar el art
            st = con.getConnection().prepareStatement("UPDATE articulos SET nombreArt=(?),precioArt=(?),categoriaArt=(?) WHERE idArt = (?);");
            st.setString(1, art.getNombre());
            st.setFloat(2, art.getPrecio());
            st.setInt(3, idCat);
            st.setInt(4, art.getId());
            st.execute();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Se actualizo ");
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            e.getMessage();
        }finally {
            con.cerrar();
        }
    }
```

---

Cualquier otro clase que quieran revisar les dejo el github:
https://github.com/srfrankie/Vivero/tree/master

---

EDIT: probe utilizando el metodo executeUpdate() y no hubo ningun cambio, no tengo ni idea por donde seguir buscando, cree una nueva tabla y probe, funciona correctamente, pero en esta que yo necesito no lo hace! tambien probe cambiarle el nombre al campo pero no funciona tampoco

Answer (score 0):

Echándole un vistazo rápido, en la sentencia SQL: 
UPDATE articulos SET nombreCat.....
no debería ser:
UPDATE articulos SET nombreArt.....

Comment: Si pero eso lo descubri poco despues de haber formulado el post este, lo corregi y sigue igual, hoy leyendo la documentacion de sqlite dice que para actualizar es necesario utilizar un executeUpdate() , hoy lo voy a probar y si me da resultados lo comento de nuevo